# I t_RegisterApplication(), FAILED TO establish the default connection to the WindowServer, _CGSDefaultConnection() is NULL

Tags: jenkins

Running a maven project on Jenkins. Seems to work until clicking a button and navigating to the registration page. But just before entering the email Jenkins throws this error. I tried moving from LaunchDeamons to LaunchAgents, but still doesn't work.

Also Jenkins on my Mac has been installed to all users, but not as a separate user if this makes any difference.

Any help would be appreciated